# The correct approach to return a promise from a method that makes http calls (Angular2)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want the method that makes the http call to return a promise in angular2

So far I've got

```
decisionOnRequestToJoinGroup(payload) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(payload), {'headers': contentHeader})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => resolve(response))
    .catch(err =>  reject(err));

  });

  }
```

Is this the right approach ?

Comment: Why don't you just `return this.http.post(...).map(...).toPromise()`? Or return the observable from `.map`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
decisionOnRequestToJoinGroup(payload) {    
  return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(payload), {'headers': contentHeader})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .toPromise();
}
```

you can then resolve it like this:

```
this.decisionOnRequestToJoinGroup(payload)
   .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
   ;})
```